# What is the closest for `cp` to `rsync -a`?

Tags: rsync, cp, coreutils

From manpage of `rsync`,

> ```
> -a, --archive
> ```
>
> This is equivalent to `-rlptgoD`. It is a quick way of saying you want
>   recursion and want to preserve almost everything (with -H being a
>   notable omission). The only exception to the above equivalenceis when
>   --files-from is specified, in which case -r is not implied.
>
> Note that -a does not preserve hardlinks, because finding
>   multiply-linked files is expensive. You must separately specify -H.

What is the closest for `cp` to `rsync -a`, in terms of input and result of file copy, ignoring transfer speed?

What does `cp -arl` miss compare to `rsync -a`? Only `-D` of `rsync`?

Does `cp -arl` behave the same as `rsync -a` except those aspects it misses?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

Note that `rsync -a` also doesn't preserve ACLs, extended attributes, hard links (as already noted), sparseness.

With GNU `cp` at least

```
cp -a
```

Preserves all that so does more than `rsync`. A closer rsync equivalent would be

```
rsync -aAHX
```

I don't think rsync can replicate the sparseness, but you can use `--sparse` so that sequences of NULs (whether they are allocated or holes) turn into holes in the destination.

Note that the (non-standard) `-a` option of `cp` implies `-r`. `-l` (another non-standard option), assuming GNU `cp` doesn't do what you want. It makes hard links *instead* of copying files.

Comment: Thanks. the `cp` I mentioned is from coreutils.